# how to remove top links from some .phtml pages

Tags: toplinks

visit the link : http://2.kidsdial.com/

on top right you can see :

"My account, My wishlist...etc"

I want to hide these links from some .phtml pages.

for example from this page : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/

Comment: on which page you want to hide

Comment: http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/

Comment: use this     <marketplace-index-index  translate="label">
<reference name="top.links">
   <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
   <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
</reference>
</marketplace-index-index>

Comment: it's not working......

Comment: it's working for me it's removed wishlist and checkout link if you want you add what and all you have

Comment: got it, you gave "-" instead of "_" underscore, now its working, thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fro example if you want to remove for product view page you can simply add you in local.xml

```
<marketplace_index_index>
<reference name="top.links">
   <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
   <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
</reference>
</marketplace_index_index>
```

Comment: suppose if i want to remove this page : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/ ?

Comment: maintenance_index_index   i think this  is the page

Comment: update the answer

Comment: its working fine for product view page [http://2.kidsdial.com/final-dest.html/], but not for this page : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/  how to find which code need to add for which page?

Comment: sorry my mistake it marketplace not maintenance. update the answer check it

Comment: how to identify <marketplace_index_index> for this url and  "wishlist_link" for wishlist button

Comment: check the body class <body class=" marketplace-index-index">

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 sorry i don't understand what you saying..

Comment: Okay, i got now @Kothari

Comment: @QaisarSatti i wanted to know what to use to hide. ex : wishlist_link" for wishlist button , like this how about login and sign up pages?

Comment: there is not name set for them you can this code for login
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action> ..

Comment: for register you can do like that 
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/></action>

Comment: i am using this code : but its not working    .....  <marketplace_index_index>
<reference name="top.links">
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/></action>
</action>
</reference>
</marketplace_index_index>

Comment: <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/></action>  remove extra </action>